# Two Element List Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, zipper

I need to write a function that determines if the given list is a pair of elements. The program will simply respond #t if the list contains exactly two elements or #f if it does not, such that:

```
(zipper? '((a 1)(b 2))) => #t
```

and

```
(zipper? '((foo 100)(bar 2 3))) => #f
```

I'm still fairly new to Scheme so any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to check whether a list has exactly two elements (which you  say) or whether a list contains only two-element lists (which your second example seems to imply?

Comment: My answer takes into account both of the cases mentioned by @molbdnilo , which one was correct? and don't forget to accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear if the "correct" input for the procedure is an arbitrary list or a two-element list. If it's strictly a two-element list, this will work:

```
(define (is-two-element-list? lst)
  (and (list? lst)
       (= (length lst) 2)))

(define (zipper? lst)
  (and (is-two-element-list? lst)
       (is-two-element-list? (first lst))
       (is-two-element-list? (second lst))))
```

… And if it's an arbitrary-length list whose elements we want to check, this will work in Racket, using [`andmap`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._andmap%29%29):

```
(define (zipper? lst)
  (andmap is-two-element-list? lst))
```

If you are not using Racket, then this solution using [`every`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#every) will work in any interpreter with SRFIs:

```
(require srfi/1)

(define (zipper? lst)
  (every is-two-element-list? lst))
```

Either way, notice that the trick was defining the `is-two-element-list?` procedure, which verifies the two-element-list property, after that we can apply it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way.  If the `zipper` list is `'()` then the answer is `#t`.  If the `zipper` list is not `'()` then if the first element is two elements and the rest is another `zipper?`, then return `#t`.

```
(define (zipper? list)
  (or (null? list)
      (and (= 2 (length (car list)))
           (zipper? (cdr list)))))
```

or maybe you mean:

```
(define (zipper? list)
  (or (not (pair? list))
      (and (= 2 (length list))
           (zipper? (list-ref list 0))
           (zipper? (list-ref list 1)))))
```

every element, at any level, has two elements.

```
> (zipper? '((a 1 2) '(b)))
#f
> (zipper? '(a b))
#t
> (zipper? '(((a (b b)) c) (1 2)))
#t
```